# Открытие WSDL как XML в браузере (.htaccess)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess

Подскажите как реализовать открытие файла в браузере.

Есть некий web сервис с расширение **WSDL**

При открытии ссылки

```
http://mysite.ru/soap/test.wsdl
```

файл скачивается, а надо чтобы он открылся в браузере как XML

Как мне правильно написать .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять заголовок при выдаче документа:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml')
```

Comment: т.е. дополнительно написать php, для вызова файла с подменой заголовка? У меня получается это прямая ссылка на файл WSDL (у него структура как у XML), обычные XML открываются в браузере, а вот с WSDL совсем другая история.

Comment: в общем, на будущее для других, кто столкнется с таким моментом. Сделал следующее: в файле **.htaccess** добавил следующие строчки `RewriteEngine On 
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
    # Регулярное выражения, по которому определяется применять ли правила 
    <filesMatch "\.(wsdl)$"> 
        # Добавляем/изменяем заголовок Content-Type 
        Header set Content-Type "text/xml" 
    </filesMatch> 
</ifModule>`